# Is banned.h alive?

Tags: c++

Banned.h was for several years touted as a SDL tool for C++ which could be downloaded from Microsoft as download item 24817. It looks like Microsoft has removed the file.Following link from online sources repeatedly end up at the Microsoft download center with a 404.
What is the fate of Banned.h? Has it been superseded with something else?

Comment: Is it that one https://github.com/mozilla/spidernode/blob/master/deps/chakrashim/core/lib/common/Banned.h and/or https://github.com/mubix/netview/blob/master/banned.h ? Maybe they just moved it onto some account/repo on github, like with aspnet core

Comment: There *are* [mirrors](https://github.com/mozilla/spidernode/blob/master/deps/chakrashim/core/lib/common/Banned.h)

Comment: I know about those. My question is about whether banned.h is deprecated or is still maintained and has Microsoft support.

Comment: Removed the SDL tag, since it's for the library called SDL, as description says.

Comment: I think the library was banned.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is still alive, I mean it is still reasonable to keep this header in your code. The most up-to-date version is available here:
https://github.com/x509cert/banned
You will also find some useful information in the README.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty certain they just made their undesirable functions reported as such by default, and you have to use `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` to *stop* being warned about them.

This makes sense from a security viewpoint since things should be *more* secure by default and require extra effort to make them less secure.

---

That ignores the fact, of course, that it's still relatively easy to screw things up if you misuse the "safe" (or security-enhanced) functions.

By that I mean such things as providing incorrect buffer sizes for `strcpy_s`, or giving an invalid but non-null pointer to `fopen_s`, which is, surprisingly, why they deprecated the original ones in the first place :-)

The unsafe ones are perfectly okay to use if you know what you're doing.